# How do I reduce this: $\frac{2}{x\ln(4)}\quad ?$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

$$\text{Given}\;\;\frac{2}{x\ln(4)}, \;\;\text{how does it reduce to}\; \frac{1}{x\ln(2)}\quad ?$$

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid now.

Comment: don't, mostly everyone stumbles at one point or another onto something quite obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $$\ln\left(a^b\right) = b \ln(a)$$

Then $$\frac{2}{x\ln(4)} = \frac{2}{x\ln\left(2^2\right)} =  \frac 2{2x\ln (2)} = \frac 1{x\ln (2)}$$

Comment: I am learning again Amy. :+)

Answer (score 2):

ln(4)=2ln(2). Therefore, you can cancel away the "2".

Answer (score 2):

Use the well-know properties of logarithm, namely
$$\log (2^2)=2\log(2)$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use $ln(4)=ln(2^2)=2ln(2)$ (log laws).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the fact that
$$
\ln(AB)=\ln(A)+\ln(B)
$$
to get
$$
\frac{2}{x\ln(4)}=\frac{2}{x(\ln(2)+\ln(2))}=\frac{2}{2x\ln(2)}=\frac{1}{x\ln(2)}.
$$